# wildcard search in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

Currently i use below wildcard search for my service,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION": "\*collaboration\*services\*shiriyara\*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This returns me expected result. But i am looking for alternative ways to achieve this without using wildcard query, as wildcard takes more time.

I tried "query_string" on a "standard" analyzed field. But this returns result if whole word matches.

```
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION",
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "query": "collaboration services shiriyara"
          }
```

If the string is "collab services shiriyara", it won't give any result, whereas wildcard gives.

Let me know, if anybody has thoughts. Index time changes also fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

You could break up your wildcards as follows, which would work for the example you have given:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"wildcard": {"PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION": "collab*"}},
        {"wildcard": {"PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION": "serv*"}},
        {"wildcard": {"PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION": "shiri*"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could look at using [ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) at index time, which would allow matching of character sequences within a word.

Comment: i don't want to use wildcard query.

Comment: I tried ngram with this metadata..... "ngram_filter": {
"type": "ngram",
"min_gram": "3",
"max_gram": "10"
}........ "ngramAnalyzerKey": {
"filter": [
"lowercase"
,
"ngram_filter"
],
"type": "custom",
"tokenizer": "keyword"
}.....This matches if any of the word in query string matches...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but in case anyone comes across it again: in Elasticsearch 7.9 a new [wildcard field type](https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field) optimised for quickly finding patterns inside string values has been introduced.